# NSAsynchronousFetchResult doesn't respect the sort order

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, core-data

This is the defintion of my fetch request and I use the score attribute to sort:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[Product entityName]];
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ProductAttributes.score ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor ]];
```

and I use this to define my async fetch:

```
 NSAsynchronousFetchRequest *asynchronousFetchRequest = [[NSAsynchronousFetchRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest completionBlock:^(NSAsynchronousFetchResult *result) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Process Asynchronous Fetch Result
            [weakSelf processAsynchronousFetchResult:result];
        });
    }];
```

and perfenter code hereorm the fetch in manged object context:

```
// Execute Asynchronous Fetch Request

    [moc performBlock:^{
        // Execute Asynchronous Fetch Request
        NSError *asynchronousFetchRequestError = nil;
        NSAsynchronousFetchResult *asynchronousFetchResult = (NSAsynchronousFetchResult *)[moc executeRequest:asynchronousFetchRequest error:&asynchronousFetchRequestError];

        if (asynchronousFetchRequestError) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to execute asynchronous fetch result.");
            NSLog(@"%@, %@", asynchronousFetchRequestError, asynchronousFetchRequestError.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
```

I put this in my completion function and it fails most of the time. the sort works but sometimes it's off by 1 or 2 in the set. Assuming score from 0 to n for n items:

```
- (void)processAsynchronousFetchResult:(NSAsynchronousFetchResult *)asynchronousFetchResult {

        if (asynchronousFetchResult.finalResult) {

          [_items addObjectsFromArray:asynchronousFetchResult.finalResult];

          for(int i=0 ; i<_items.count ; i++) {            
             Product *product = _items[i];
             assert([product.score intValue]==i);
         }
       }
}
```

The same thing with normal fetch results controller works fine for sorting. Any idea why async fetch breaks the sorting and is there a way to enforce that.